# where I can find update zmq tutorial?

Tags: c, zeromq

I have the following page useful http://www.zeromq.org/code:examples-chat

However, it indicates that "*This text is deprecated and refers to an old version of ØMQ. It remains here for historical interest. DO NOT USE THIS TO LEARN ØMQ.*"

Question> Where I can find the updated tutorials for zmq?

Thank you

Comment: The front page has links, e.g. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all

Comment: It's quite amazing how you found the old chat example but didn't see the many links to the online docs. How did you get to this page?

Comment: Search "zmq chat program" through google. First link. BTW, like your book!

Comment: @PieterHintjens How relevant is the old chat example despite being on the old code base? Do the same principals apply? Is it worth studying?